# Why can I not capture the value in my input field? (JS/HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, text, input

I am trying to create a validation function for my input field, problem is I cannot capture what is in my input field!!

When I run test and put something in my input field, it returns nothing...

This is my code

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" onsubmit="test();">
<style type="text/css">
.botLayout{
padding-right:130px;
margin-right:20px;
}
</style>
<div class="botLayout">
<div name="title" align="left" style="font-size: 13px;">
<font size="4"><b>
REGISTER NOW
</b></font>
</div>
<div name="indic" align="right" style="font-size: 13px;">
<font size="1">
<font color="#ff0000">*</font>Required field
</font>
</div>
<b style="font-weight: bold;">
<div>
<div>
<div>
<b style="font-size: 13px;">First Name</b><b>
<div style="display: inline !important;">
<div style="display: inline !important;">
<span style="color: #ff0000; font-weight: normal; text-align: -webkit-right;"><font size="2">*</font></span>
</div>
</div>
</b>
</div>
<div style="font-size: 13px;">
<input type="text" maxlength="50" name="First Name" id="First Name" value="%%first name%%" size="19" />
</div>
</div>
<div>
<div>
<b style="font-size: 13px;">Last Name</b><b>
<div style="display: inline !important;">
<div style="display: inline !important;">
<span style="color: #ff0000; font-weight: normal; text-align: -webkit-right;"><font size="2">*</font></span>
</div>
</div>
</b>
</div>
<div style="font-size: 13px;">
<input type="text" maxlength="50" name="Last Name" id="Last Name" value="" size="19" />
</div>
</div>
<div>
<div>
<b style="font-size: 13px;">Email</b><b>
<div style="display: inline !important;">
<div style="display: inline !important;">
<span style="color: #ff0000; font-weight: normal; text-align: -webkit-right;"><font size="2">*</font></span>
</div>
</div>
</b>
</div>
<div style="font-size: 13px;">
<input type="text" maxlength="254" name="Email" id="Email" value="" size="19" />
</div>
</div>
<div>
<div>
<b style="font-size: 13px;">Company</b><b>
<div style="display: inline !important;">
<div style="display: inline !important;">
<span style="color: #ff0000; font-weight: normal; text-align: -webkit-right;"><font size="2">*</font></span>
</div>
</div>
</b>
</div>
<div style="font-size: 13px;">
<input type="text" maxlength="50" name="Company" id="Company" value="" size="19" />
</div>
</div>
<div>
<div>
<b style="font-size: 13px;">Job Title</b><b>
<div style="display: inline !important;">
<div style="display: inline !important;">
<span style="color: #ff0000; font-weight: normal; text-align: -webkit-right;"><font size="2">*</font></span>
</div>
</div>
</b>
</div>
<div style="font-size: 13px;">
<input type="text" maxlength="50" name="Job Title" id="Job Title" value="" size="19" />
</div>
</div>
<div style="font-size: 13px;">
<div>
<b>Contact Phone number</b>
</div>
<div>
<input type="text" maxlength="50" name="Contact Phone number" id="Contact Phone number" value="" size="19" />
</div>
</div>
<div>
<div>
<b style="font-size: 13px;">Event Location</b><b>
<div style="display: inline !important;">
<div style="display: inline !important;">
<span style="color: #ff0000; font-weight: normal; text-align: -webkit-right;"><font size="2">*</font></span>
</div>
</div>
</b>
</div>
<div style="font-size: 13px;">
<select name="Event Location" id="Event Location">
<option value="Please select" selected="selected">
Please select</option>
<option value="Adelaide">
Adelaide</option>
<option value="Canberra">
Canberra</option>
<option value="Melbourne">
Melbourne</option>
<option value="Sydney">
Sydney</option></select>
</div>
<div style="font-size: 13px;">
&nbsp;
</div>
<div style="font-size: 13px;">
<p class="MsoNormal">
<span style="font-size: 9pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #333333;">By providing your details above you are consenting to receive
communications from SMS Management & Technology in the future, on the
understanding that you have read and agree to our </span><a href="http://www.smsmt.com/AU/Privacy-Statement" target="_blank" title="http://www.smsmt.com/AU/Privacy-Statement" alias="http://www.smsmt.com/AU/Privacy-Statement" conversion="false"><span style="font-size: 9pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">Privacy Statement</span></a><span style="font-size: 9pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #333333;">.<o:p></o:p></span>
</p>
<p class="MsoNormal">
<span style="font-size: 9pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #333333;">As this event is supported by Rally Software, you also consent
to receive communication from them, according to their <a href="http://www.rallydev.com/privacy-statement " title="https://www.rallydev.com/privacy-statement " alias="https://www.rallydev.com/privacy-statement " conversion="false">Privacy Statement</a>. You
will be able to opt-out of communications at any time.</span><span style="color: #1f497d;"><o:p></o:p></span>
</p>
</div>
</div>
<div style="font-size: 13px;">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
</div>
<span style="display: none;" id="post_code">%%[[name="FormPost";type="POST"] 
VAR @de, @de_col, @updateOptions, @saveOptions, @de_statusCode, @de_statusMsg, @errorCode
SET @de = CreateObject("DataExtensionObject")
SetObjectProperty(@de, "CustomerKey", "AgileforGovRegistered")
SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "Email")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", RequestParameter("Email"))
AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Keys", @de_col)
IF NOT IsNull(RequestParameter("First Name")) THEN
SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "First Name")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", RequestParameter("First Name"))
AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Properties", @de_col)
ENDIF
IF NOT IsNull(RequestParameter("Last Name")) THEN
SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "Last Name")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", RequestParameter("Last Name"))
AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Properties", @de_col)
ENDIF
IF NOT IsNull(RequestParameter("Email")) THEN
SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "Email")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", RequestParameter("Email"))
AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Properties", @de_col)
ENDIF
IF NOT IsNull(RequestParameter("Company")) THEN
SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "Company")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", RequestParameter("Company"))
AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Properties", @de_col)
ENDIF
IF NOT IsNull(RequestParameter("Company")) THEN
SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "Job Title")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", RequestParameter("Company"))
AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Properties", @de_col)
ENDIF
IF NOT IsNull(RequestParameter("Contact Phone number")) THEN
SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "Contact Phone number")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", RequestParameter("Contact Phone number"))
AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Properties", @de_col)
ENDIF
IF NOT IsNull(RequestParameter("Event Location")) THEN
SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "Event Location")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", RequestParameter("Event Location"))
AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Properties", @de_col)
ENDIF
SET @updateOptions = CreateObject("UpdateOptions")
SET @saveOptions = CreateObject("SaveOption")
SetObjectProperty(@saveOptions, "PropertyName", "DataExtensionObject")
SetObjectProperty(@saveOptions, "SaveAction", "UpdateAdd")
AddObjectArrayItem(@updateOptions, "SaveOptions", @saveOptions)
SET @de_statusCode = InvokeUpdate(@de, @de_statusMsg, @errorCode, @updateOptions)
IF @de_statusCode != "OK" THEN
RaiseError(@de_statusMsg, 0, @de_statusCode, @errorCode)
ENDIF
VAR @ts, @tsDef, @ts_sub, @ts_attr, @tsctr, @ts_subkey, @ts_statusCode, @ts_statusMsg, @errorCode
SET @ts = CreateObject("TriggeredSend")
SET @tsDef = CreateObject("TriggeredSendDefinition")
SET @ts_subkey = RequestParameter("Email")
SetObjectProperty(@tsDef, "CustomerKey", "AgileForGovConfirmation")
SetObjectProperty(@ts, "TriggeredSendDefinition", @tsDef)
SET @ts_sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "EmailAddress", RequestParameter("Email"))
IF NOT EMPTY(@ts_subkey) THEN
SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "SubscriberKey", @ts_subkey)
ELSE
SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "SubscriberKey", RequestParameter("Email"))
ENDIF
IF NOT IsNull(RequestParameter("First Name")) THEN
SET @ts_attr = CreateObject("Attribute")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_attr, "Name", "First Name")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_attr, "Value", RequestParameter("First Name"))
AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @ts_attr)
ENDIF
AddObjectArrayItem(@ts, "Subscribers", @ts_sub)
SET @ts_statusCode = InvokeCreate(@ts, @ts_statusMsg, @errorCode)
IF @ts_statusCode != "OK" THEN
RaiseError(@ts_statusMsg, 0, @ts_statusCode, @errorCode)
ENDIF
]%%</span>
<span style="display: none;" id="post_code">%%[[name="FormPost";type="POST"] 
VAR @de, @de_col, @updateOptions, @saveOptions, @de_statusCode, @de_statusMsg, @errorCode
SET @de = CreateObject("DataExtensionObject")
SetObjectProperty(@de, "CustomerKey", "AgileforGovRegistered")
SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "Email")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", RequestParameter("Email"))
AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Keys", @de_col)
IF NOT IsNull(RequestParameter("First Name")) THEN
SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "First Name")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", RequestParameter("First Name"))
AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Properties", @de_col)
ENDIF
IF NOT IsNull(RequestParameter("Last Name")) THEN
SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "Last Name")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", RequestParameter("Last Name"))
AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Properties", @de_col)
ENDIF
IF NOT IsNull(RequestParameter("Email")) THEN
SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "Email")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", RequestParameter("Email"))
AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Properties", @de_col)
ENDIF
IF NOT IsNull(RequestParameter("Company")) THEN
SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "Company")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", RequestParameter("Company"))
AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Properties", @de_col)
ENDIF
IF NOT IsNull(RequestParameter("Company")) THEN
SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "Job Title")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", RequestParameter("Company"))
AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Properties", @de_col)
ENDIF
IF NOT IsNull(RequestParameter("Contact Phone number")) THEN
SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "Contact Phone number")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", RequestParameter("Contact Phone number"))
AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Properties", @de_col)
ENDIF
IF NOT IsNull(RequestParameter("Event Location")) THEN
SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "Event Location")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", RequestParameter("Event Location"))
AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Properties", @de_col)
ENDIF
SET @updateOptions = CreateObject("UpdateOptions")
SET @saveOptions = CreateObject("SaveOption")
SetObjectProperty(@saveOptions, "PropertyName", "DataExtensionObject")
SetObjectProperty(@saveOptions, "SaveAction", "UpdateAdd")
AddObjectArrayItem(@updateOptions, "SaveOptions", @saveOptions)
SET @de_statusCode = InvokeUpdate(@de, @de_statusMsg, @errorCode, @updateOptions)
IF @de_statusCode != "OK" THEN
RaiseError(@de_statusMsg, 0, @de_statusCode, @errorCode)
ENDIF
VAR @ts, @tsDef, @ts_sub, @ts_attr, @tsctr, @ts_subkey, @ts_statusCode, @ts_statusMsg, @errorCode
SET @ts = CreateObject("TriggeredSend")
SET @tsDef = CreateObject("TriggeredSendDefinition")
SET @ts_subkey = RequestParameter("Email")
SetObjectProperty(@tsDef, "CustomerKey", "AgileForGovConfirmation")
SetObjectProperty(@ts, "TriggeredSendDefinition", @tsDef)
SET @ts_sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "EmailAddress", RequestParameter("Email"))
IF NOT EMPTY(@ts_subkey) THEN
SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "SubscriberKey", @ts_subkey)
ELSE
SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "SubscriberKey", RequestParameter("Email"))
ENDIF
IF NOT IsNull(RequestParameter("First Name")) THEN
SET @ts_attr = CreateObject("Attribute")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_attr, "Name", "First Name")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_attr, "Value", RequestParameter("First Name"))
AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @ts_attr)
ENDIF
AddObjectArrayItem(@ts, "Subscribers", @ts_sub)
SET @ts_statusCode = InvokeCreate(@ts, @ts_statusMsg, @errorCode)
IF @ts_statusCode != "OK" THEN
RaiseError(@ts_statusMsg, 0, @ts_statusCode, @errorCode)
ENDIF
]%%</span><span style="display: none;" id="post_code"><!-- AMP Processing Placeholder DO NOT REMOVE --></span>
</b>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var a=document.forms["myForm"]["First Name"].value;
var b=document.forms["myForm"]["Last Name"].value;
var c=document.forms["myForm"]["Email Address"].value;
var d=document.forms["myForm"]["Company"].value;
var e=document.forms["myForm"]["Job Title"].value;
function test()
{
if(1===1){
alert(a);
alert(b);
event.preventDefault();
return false; 
}
}
</script>
<input type="hidden" name="__successPage" id="__successPage" value="http://pages.s7.exacttarget.com/agileforgovconfirmation/" /><input type="hidden" name="__errorPage" id="__errorPage" value="" /><input type="hidden" name="__contextName" id="__contextName" value="FormPost" /><input type="hidden" name="__executionContext" id="__executionContext" value="Post" />
```

Scroll to the bottom and look at the text/JS style, I've been testing for ages and I just can't figure it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use form elements like array collection to access it's value.
Because the `document.forms['idOfForm']` will return form element not an array.

And for web standards you should not use space in element name and id.

Here is the working form of your code 
http://jsfiddle.net/vcgquvh7/

Comment: You can reference elements via the names with bracket notation. http://jsfiddle.net/5ocf1csd

Comment: Thank you kindly! I got it working thanks to your help

Answer (score 0):

Valid id and name attributes can not contains spaces.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id

Solution: Remove the spaces.

---

Other problems:

First is you are reading the value on render, you are not reading them when he form is submitted. When the value changes, it does not magically update the variable. Move the code where you read the values inside of the function.

You also never declare `event` so you have an undefined variable.

You return from the function, but your onsumbit handler does not handle the return.

---

1: Remove the whitespace from the names and ids

2: Fix the onsubmit hander

```
<form onsubmit="return test()">
```

3: Move the reading of the fields into the test function

```
function test (event) {
    var a=document.forms["myForm"]["FirstName"].value;
    var b=document.forms["myForm"]["LastName"].value;
    var c=document.forms["myForm"]["EmailAddress"].value;
    var d=document.forms["myForm"]["Company"].value;
    var e=document.forms["myForm"]["JobTitle"].value;
    if(1===1){
        alert(a);
        alert(b);
        //event.preventDefault();
        return false; 
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi epascarello! I have tried changing it and it does not seem to be the problem :/

Comment: Well you read the values on render, that is your other issue.